# Lynx skip receiving arguments from stdin (post_data)

Tags: linux, post, stdin, lynx

I'm trying to send post request with lynx

```
lynx -source -mime_header -post_data http://localhost/post.php
```

This redirects me to stdin to type foo=bar *return* --- *return* and then lynx sends request, but i need to send it immediately avoiding stdin typing (/post.php just prints $_POST array)

This command should looks like `lynx -source -mime_header -post_data foo=bar http://localhost/post.php`
but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: You can just emulate stdin input with pipe (`echo -e 'foo=bar\n---\n' | lynx ...`)

Comment: You are the man! Many thanks!! It works!! `echo -e 'foo=bar\n---\n' | lynx -source -mime_header -post_data http://localhost/post.php`